# How to check network connection type in Blackberry?

Tags: networking, blackberry, java-me, connection

In Blackberry application I want to check what type of network connection is being used on particular phone, whether it is BES/MDS,BIS-B or Direct Tcp.
Is there any way to find out this?

Many applications like Jive,Opera and many more are doing this kind of check.

Please help.

Comment: Do you mean "How do I check for available connectivity"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question springs from an incorrect assumption. A Blackberry could be communicating over any or all of those channels simultaneously. In fact any application may as well. At any particular time you can determine if coverage is sufficient for one of those channels, or register a listener for notification of changing status using net.rim.device.api.system.CoverageInfo.

Answer (score 4):

The question is quite logical and I do agree with Richard as well. Though a better answer lies in the fact that there can be a logic developed which would involve Service Book parsing and making use of system listeners to check the current coverage status.

I had attempted to make one such logic once in my project which worked for me. I had shared my findings and understanding about the concept in more detail at my blog post. May be you would like to check once.

You can find my blog post [here](http://bbdevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/08/httpconnection-over-bis-wap-10-11-wap.html).

Comment: Hi Sameer,Thanks for your valuable answer.And your blog post helped me a lot.I went through the source code provided by you.Handling network types in Blackberry was a headache for me....Kudos to you.